# Конвертация из XLS в XML

Tags: php

Всем доброго дня.

Помогите, пожалуйста, нужен скрипт для сохранения файла формата xls в формате xml или подскажите, как его написать.

Спасибо всем заранее.

Answer (score 1):

1. Конвертировать xls в массив с помощью [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/).
2. Конвертировать массив в xml с помощью [скрипта](http://snipplr.com/view/3491/convert-php-array-to-xml-or-simple-xml-object-if-you-wish/).